# Many errors in Backend API

Tags: besu, blockscout

I'm trying to run Blockscout by follow [this](https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout/tree/master/docker-compose).

1. I have 5 Besu nodes running fine.
2. I can see all Blockscout components running without any error.
3. The Backend API component was done the database creation. I can check all tables was created and have been populated with some data from my chain.
4. After done with the [database migration](https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout/blob/master/docker-compose/services/backend.yml) `Elixir.Explorer.ReleaseTasks.create_and_migrate()` and ran `bin/blockscout start` I can see some `DBConnection.ConnectionError` and  a `Kernel pid terminated` and a `Crash dump` .

```
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.313Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.316Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.316Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.316Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-02-03 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.316Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-02-03 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.321Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.321Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.321Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.323Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.324Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.324Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-02-04 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.324Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-02-04 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.327Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.330Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.330Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.330Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-02-05 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.330Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-02-05 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.333Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.336Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.336Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.336Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-02-06 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.336Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-02-06 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.340Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.342Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.342Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.342Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: records collected [%{date: ~D[2024-02-06], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-05], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-04], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-03], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-02], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-01], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-01-31], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-01-30], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-01-29], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}]","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.342Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: save records","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:18:55.344Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: number of inserted 10","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.338Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4260.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) client #PID<0.5183.0> exited","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.346Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.346Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.366Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4255.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) client #PID<0.5298.0> exited","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.372Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.372Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.394Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4218.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) client #PID<0.5413.0> exited","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.396Z","severity":"info","message":"Application indexer exited: shutdown","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.338Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4260.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) client #PID<0.5183.0> exited","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.346Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.346Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.366Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4255.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) client #PID<0.5298.0> exited","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.372Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.372Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.394Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4218.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) client #PID<0.5413.0> exited","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.396Z","severity":"info","message":"Application indexer exited: shutdown","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.413Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4205.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.413Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4246.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.413Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4214.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.413Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4211.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.413Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4212.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.413Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4248.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.414Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4213.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.414Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4267.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
{"time":"2024-02-07T03:22:05.414Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4270.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4672.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
...
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_terminated,indexer,shutdown}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_terminated,indexer,shutdown})
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

Here is my database log:

```
2024-02-07 12:34:29.299 UTC [2143] LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
2024-02-07 12:34:29.299 UTC [2143] FATAL:  connection to client lost
2024-02-07 12:34:29.324 UTC [2170] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2024-02-07 12:34:29.324 UTC [2170] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM "missing_block_ranges" AS m0 USING "missing_block_ranges" AS m1 WHERE ((((((m1."from_number" <= m0."from_number") AND (m1."from_number" >= m0."to_number")) OR ((m1."to_number" <= m0."from_number") AND (m1."to_number" >= m0."to_number"))) OR ((m0."from_number" <= m1."from_number") AND (m0."from_number" >= m1."to_number"))) OR ((m0."to_number" <= m1."from_number") AND (m0."to_number" >= m1."to_number"))) AND (m1."id" != m0."id")) RETURNING m0."id", m0."from_number", m0."to_number"
2024-02-07 12:34:29.325 UTC [2170] LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
2024-02-07 12:34:29.325 UTC [2170] FATAL:  connection to client lost
2024-02-07 12:34:29.351 UTC [2118] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2024-02-07 12:34:29.351 UTC [2118] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM "missing_block_ranges" AS m0 USING "missing_block_ranges" AS m1 WHERE ((((((m1."from_number" <= m0."from_number") AND (m1."from_number" >= m0."to_number")) OR ((m1."to_number" <= m0."from_number") AND (m1."to_number" >= m0."to_number"))) OR ((m0."from_number" <= m1."from_number") AND (m0."from_number" >= m1."to_number"))) OR ((m0."to_number" <= m1."from_number") AND (m0."to_number" >= m1."to_number"))) AND (m1."id" != m0."id")) RETURNING m0."id", m0."from_number", m0."to_number"
2024-02-07 12:34:29.352 UTC [2118] LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
2024-02-07 12:34:29.352 UTC [2118] FATAL:  connection to client lost
2024-02-07 12:34:59.696 UTC [26] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-02-07 12:35:00.803 UTC [26] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 12 buffers (0.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=1.104 s, sync=0.001 s, total=1.108 s; sync files=10, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=24 kB, estimate=24 kB
```

Comment: Rolled back to ```5.2.3.commit.f89f344e``` and unset ```ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_WS_URL``` and it worked well but ```6.1.0``` don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my adventure until now (every try is with a new fresh clean database. No migrations):

I've decided to rollback to `5.2.3.commit.f89f344e` and it worked very well. No errors.

So I go right to the `5.2.3.commit.9cba3b22` version, but I received many errors too.

Going a little back to `5.2.3.commit.9acb4533` and received error related to too many connections (seems the Blockscout guys decided to be more clear about what was going wrong). Will think about connections later. Now I'll go back a little more until I find the last working version...

```
2024-02-07T15:12:04.926 application=db_connection [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4378.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections) sorry, too many clients already
2024-02-07T15:12:04.926 application=db_connection [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4374.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections) sorry, too many clients already
2024-02-07T15:12:04.927 application=db_connection [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4372.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections) sorry, too many clients already
2024-02-07T15:12:04.964 [notice] Application explorer exited: Explorer.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Explorer.Chain.Events.Listener
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:bad_return_from_init, {:stop, %Postgrex.Error{message: nil, postgres: %{code: :too_many_connections, file: "proc.c", line: "357", message: "sorry, too many clients already", pg_code: "53300", routine: "InitProcess", severity: "FATAL", unknown: "FATAL"}, connection_id: nil, query: nil}, %Postgrex.SimpleConnection{idle_interval: 5000, protocol: nil, auto_reconnect: false, reconnect_backoff: 500, state: {Postgrex.Notifications, %Postgrex.Notifications{from: nil, ref: nil, auto_reconnect: false, connected: false, listeners: %{}, listener_channels: %{}}}}}}}
            (explorer 5.2.3) lib/explorer/chain/events/listener.ex:17: Explorer.Chain.Events.Listener.init/1
            (stdlib 3.17) gen_server.erl:423: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib 3.17) gen_server.erl:390: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib 3.17) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

With `5.2.3.commit.c70968c7` we are back to the obscure days... I received this error over and over forever:

```
Retrying.
2024-02-07T15:35:59.975 application=indexer fetcher=block_catchup first_block_number=20855 last_block_number=20846 [error] ** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: []
    (hackney 1.19.1) /app/deps/hackney/src/hackney_url.erl:248: :hackney_url.parse_netloc/2
    (hackney 1.19.1) /app/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:691: :hackney.proxy_from_url/5
    (hackney 1.19.1) /app/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:335: :hackney.request/5
    (httpoison 2.1.0) lib/httpoison/base.ex:872: HTTPoison.Base.request/6
    (ethereum_jsonrpc 5.2.3) lib/ethereum_jsonrpc/http/httpoison.ex:12: EthereumJSONRPC.HTTP.HTTPoison.json_rpc/4
    (ethereum_jsonrpc 5.2.3) lib/ethereum_jsonrpc/http.ex:73: EthereumJSONRPC.HTTP.chunked_json_rpc/3
    (ethereum_jsonrpc 5.2.3) lib/ethereum_jsonrpc/request_coordinator.ex:87: anonymous fn/3 in EthereumJSONRPC.RequestCoordinator.perform/4
    (ethereum_jsonrpc 5.2.3) lib/ethereum_jsonrpc/request_coordinator.ex:107: EthereumJSONRPC.RequestCoordinator.trace_request/2
```

Found the last working version: `5.2.3.commit.ea55f5ca` the versions newer than that (including `5.2.3.commit.4d49a278`) are not working anymore.

Now I'll check the client limits for the database if it the source of the problem, but the application is resilient to this until the tag `5.2.3.commit.ea55f5ca`. Newer versions will complain and/or crash.